# Convection and the Strouhal number

Tags: fluid-dynamics, convection

Whenever I look into information about the Strouhal number, I always see it reference vortex shredding. But the Strouhal number can also be used in the context of turbulent convection where
$$
St=\frac{\tau_c}{\ell/u}.
$$
Here $\tau_c$ is the correlation time of the convection and $\ell/u$ is the turnover time. Now the Strouhal number is usually a function of the Reynolds number. In this case, I would assume that increasing the Reynolds number decreases the Strouhal number. If the convection is laminar and steady, then clearly St is infinite. It is turbulence that causes the convective pattern to shift constantly, hence lower St.

Now, I am looking for references that discuss in detail the Strouhal number in different contexts, not just vortex shredding. In particular I am interested to know if the value of St=0.2 found in vortex shredding is universal or not. And if there are any reasons why we measure this particular value. In the convection case I am interested in, I find several values of St, but one of them is St=0.2 (another one is 0.4), which is remarkable. Yet the situation is completely different from vortex shredding. Are there any arguments to predict the value of St?